# Shows Access violation error while simulator loads

Tags: blackberry

i just downloaded JDE 1.1 Plugin for eclipse,and i installed it and while i run the application ,on loading of simulator it shows access violation error.i tried running clean.bat ad i installed the files in Non Windows Directory.but no thing worked and it showed the same error.Any New Suggestions For cleating that error and i use JDK 1.6 UPdate 10

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the simulator you have is buggy or corrupted.  Try installing a different simulator - you can grab them from [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp).

Comment: Hi Marc,It is simulator with which it contains 5.0 JDE and i want to know ,how to change the simulator in this in built JDE(5.0)in Eclipse.

i use Eclipse 1.1 plugin,is it possible to integrate the Jde's(4.3 to 4.7) in this Eclipse,if so how to?

Comment: Try downloading and installing the simulator (from the link provided) - it should show up in Eclipse.  You can have more than one simulator installed at a time.

Comment: Hi Marc,in this Eclipse Plugin(1.1)default simulator is 9550.I changed to tour and i just ran the simulator ,it shows the same error and the it alsp shows "Failed to connect to remote VM"